# Facebook Connect Login Dialog crashing app

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-login

Of the many problems I've been having with my current app, this is one of the most annoying.

In the simulator the login dialog works fine, however on a device it's just a frozen white box and the console prints the following:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate 
(webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:) 
failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

I've looked this up but I'm still not sure what it means.

If I try switching

`[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];`

to

`[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:YES];`

it switches to the safari app to verify but this somehow kills my app with an error which says `ReturnNotPermittedKillClient`.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem? On my last app it just worked without any of these issues, and as far as I can see I've done everything the same way this time. However this project was inherited from someone else so there may be  underlying causes that I am not aware of.

Edit: Just tried moving the login request from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to a point in the intro screen class where everything else has already been loaded, just in case it was a memory issue caused by too many tasks trying to run at the same time. This time the error message didn't appear, however the login box still remained white and then closed the app a few seconds later.

Edit2: Seems like it's simply a memory error. I changed all variables which I had previously released to be retained, which has fixed the problem on my 3GS. However on my iPad 1 the problem persists. Incidentally, when changing `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` from using landscaperight to using landscaperight or landscapeleft, when I rotate the iPad I get a memory warning and then the same crash. In both cases there are no debug error messages other than the memory warning, and the app just closes down - there is no breakpoint etc to see where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply down to memory. After changing the way it loads images, sounds etc the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the webview then we need to do this first b4 moving to next view .delegate = nil;

This might be what you want:
There are other branches of this in NSObject in the documentation.

Code:
 [self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: ]

Comment: Not sure I entirely follow you. I have tried calling the login dialog box both from the delegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, and also in the next view - neither worked. Also tried using afterDelay which made no difference, still just a white screen and then the app closes.

Comment: I always delete apps and reinstall when there is a major problem, just to be sure. Still your solution did not work I'm afraid.

Comment: To solve that problem i actually set this four properties of webview in Android, try to do this may hep you        

          webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  webView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(false);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);